# Errors while installing native modules using NSolid

Tags: nsolid

I have installed NSolid locally on my Mac. After sourcing the environment, I ran `npm install` to install the modules for my project. The 2 native modules both are failing with the same error during the build step:

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: 404 response downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.7/nsolid-v4.4.7-headers.tar.gz
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/nsolid/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:210:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onRequestResponse (/usr/local/nsolid/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:977:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:430:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:103:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:320:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
```

I'm not running a proxy, and I'm able to get to http://nodejs.org just fine. Is there a work-around for the missing headers?

Comment: Perhaps are you using`nvm`? If so then `$ unset NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR` should fix the issue.

Comment: I sure am! And that works! Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using `nvm`

```
$ unset NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
```

Should do the trick.